Getting 'The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port' error after configuring HTTP on port 80 with reverse proxy
I am getting error of
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl on;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 

Please help me to fix the error.
Thank you

ssl on is deprecated and probably the culprit here. listen <port> ssl from your config will make sure ssl is on and that is the preferred way.

See an example here

this is solved now i am facing 502 Bad Gateway is their any solution for this ?
